# Get sum of the two income values, but it gets concatenated together

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my react app screenshot. and this is my context project in AppContext,jsx file. this file handel all variables and methods in my app so I don't send you other components source code because you dont need it. I want when I click at add button the cart add with income state. you can see I did it successfully and two carts with 5$ and 7$ state created in income state. but the main challenge is the Income area. in this area that have green background and green fonts I want when I click in add btn it shows the sum of my Incoms. for example in this screenshot it should 12$ because sum of 5 and 7 is 12. now this is source code of AppContext.jsx. please help me.
[screen shot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeEiU.png)
the code :
AppContext.jsx

```js
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
// Create a context to share data across components
export const AppContext = createContext();

export default function AppContextProvider({ children }) {
  // State variables for income and expense tracking
  const [cost, setCost] = useState(0);
  const [income, setIncome] = useState(0);
  const [outcome, setOutcome] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  // State variables for transaction details
  const [describe, setDescribe] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("Income");
  // Array to store individual transactions
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  // Arrays to track total income and outcome for potential calculations
  const [totalIncome , setTotalIncome] = useState([0]);
  const [totalOitcome , setTotalOitcome] = useState([0]);
  // Function to handle adding a new transaction to the cart
  const addBtnHandel = () => {
    setCart((prev) => {
      return [
        ...prev,
        {
          id: Date.now(), // Generate a unique ID for the transaction
          cost: cost,
          describe: describe,
          type: type,
          date: date,
        },
      ];
    });
    // Calculate the new total income array
    const newTotalIncome = [...totalIncome, cost];
    // Calculate the sum of the total income array
    const totalIncomeSum = newTotalIncome.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0);
    // Update both states with the new values
    setTotalIncome(newTotalIncome);
    setIncome(totalIncomeSum);
    // Clear input fields for the next transaction
    setCost(0);
    setDescribe("");
    setDate("");
    setType("Income");
  };
  // Provide the context values to child components
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        cost,
        outcome,
        total,
        setCost,
        setDescribe,
        describe,
        type,
        setType,
        cart,
        setCart,
        income,
        setIncome,
        outcome,
        setOutcome,
        total,
        setTotal,
        date,
        setDate,
        addBtnHandel,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Income is displayed in the green area as 057 instead of 12 when I input 5 and 7.

EDITE : FIXED by this line:

```
// Calculate the new total income array
let addVal = Number(cost);
const newTotalIncome = [...totalIncome, addVal];
```

Comment: it is because one or both values are in string. Try this
const totalIncomeSum = newTotalIncome.reduce((sum, item) => +sum + +item, 0);

Comment: of course, but I cant understand how it happen. now I fix my problem just with this code:   ```// Calculate the new total income array
  let addVal = Number(cost);
  const newTotalIncome = [...totalIncome, addVal];```

Comment: Please don't add solutions inside a question. Consider creating an answer if you think this question/answer can help other people

Comment: The reason why this happens is probably because you use an `<input>` element to get the number(s) from the user. The `input.value` always returns a string. “`value` - A string that represents the current value of the control. If the user enters a value different from the value expected, this may return an empty string.” - [MDN  HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties)